# Pure C vs Kernel C vs classic C

Tags: c, standards, definition

I'm in my last year as a college student and I find myself in the perplexing situation in which, although I understand conceptually that there are some minor differences between these, like in classic C the function did not have prototypes, thankfully no longer in use, I can't pinpoint those precise distinctions among these three.
I would like some formal definitions, preferably indicating a written paper source, if there are any for:

- Pure C: what does it mean, because I've seen it used extensively, or when one should use this without being misunderstood
- Kernel C: if there are any differences between Kernel C and Pure C in the sense of *language features*.
- classic C: by this I am referring to K&R C, are there any practical uses besides legacy support? Is it useful for didactic purpose?

Any other information or guidelines for identifying the (minor but concrete) differences, etc. If there are no (or almost no) notably discrepancies, I'd be very grateful for a definition which suggests so.

*Note*:
I'm not asking about **C++**, in lack of a better word, superset, or any other **C** related languages, which inherits some syntax or formatting.
Neither I'm talking about **ANSI C99/C1X** standard, as in way/style of writing code nor I am referring to additional libraries. To be more specific, as an example, C11 allows *anonymous* `structures` and `unions`, this is a *feature* which concerns the question.
My focus is just on the language *itself and its features*, not trying to discuss libraries or compilers.
If the GNU/POSIX/ANSI/etc are now considered to include what we refer to as C, then shouldn't the terminology be GNU language?
Just to clear this out, the question is not meant to do a history of the language.

Comment: You'll have to explain what you mean by these terms, they are not standard terminology.

Comment: By "classic C" do you mean ["K&R C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29#K.26R_C)? By "pure C" do you mean [the ISO/IEC standardized C (also known as ANSI C)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29#ANSI_C_and_ISO_C)? What do you mean by "kernel C"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C

Comment: Kernel C is I think the same as ANSI C with some syntax etc. rules and I don't think POSIX? But I don't know. I don't remember 100%. But here's an interesting read that describes the history of C https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html.

Comment: "some kind of list, or guidelines of identifying the (minor but concrete) differences" Download the C11 standard draft, read page 13. Covers all changes since the first standard. What was allowed before C90 shouldn't be of much interest nowadays.

Comment: @RastaJedi If you look at the Linux kernel for example, it is most definitely not written in standard C. It relies heavily on GCC extensions.

Comment: @M.M That is exactly the problem I face, I don't know which of these terms can or should be use alternatively.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That is precisely what I mean by classic C -> K&R C. On the other hand, pure C is a term found often enough in programmers lingo, which i want to clarify.

Comment: @RastaJedi Kernel does _obey_ some rules, but Kernel C doesn't have none of the standard POSIX libraries, it has a special superset of instructions/libraries. Correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the tip.

Comment: when I've seen people say "pure C", it's because they mean "C", but they think "C" by itself is short for "C/C++"

Comment: Please clarify what exactly are you looking for? You use the word *ideologies*, are you asking about coding style or language features?

Comment: The language defined by the Standards Committee does not require that compilers support certain features which are vital for systems programming.  In the 1990s, the vast majority of compilers supported a number of features and guarantees which, while not mandated by any Standard, were widely recognized as "expected".  If one was writing a compiler for a processor where feeding -1 to a left-shift instruction would do something other than yield -2, the compiler would be allowed to expose the processor's behavior, but it was widely recognized that if every microprocessor could easily...

Comment: ...offer some behavioral guarantees, then compilers for microprocessors should make those guarantees available to programmers regardless of whether the Standard required it.  Unfortunately, even though some such guarantees are required for some kinds of programming, compiler writers have taken the attitude that the Standards Committee's failure to require that compilers for obscure hardware platforms behave like those for compilers targeting modern hardware platforms should mean that even compilers for modern platforms should not be bound by behavioral norms that had previously...

Comment: ...been unanimously upheld by compilers for modern platforms.  In their eyes, even if 100% of compilers targeting microprocessors have done something a certain way for decades, it's not a standard unless the Standards Committee requires it on all compilers for all platforms.

Comment: Ok, so I was right about no POSIX, but I don't know how I forgot but kernel C obviously uses gnu extensions.

Comment: Also, OP says old C (e.g. without prototypes for functions) isn't in use anymore. It is though, and that is why (most) compilers support legacy code. It's not *in use* in the sense that it's not used for writing new code on modern platforms, but there is older code that is still being used today. I'm interested in exactly what types of codebases and which systems are running such code and about how many still are using pre-standard C.

Comment: @RastaJedi Seriously, are you going to debate the semantics of "in use"?
[Second meaning](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+use) Not trying to be condescending, but, when I wrote "no longer in use" I meant: not being preferred anymore, as in being obsolete not excluded from the language.

Comment: @RaresSabinRusu I knew what you meant which is why I agreed that it wasn't in use in that sense anymore, I merely just wanted to mention (to others who might stumble upon this question) that codebases that use such legacy code still exist.

Comment: @supercat If this question goes off on hold, please post your comments as response, I find them very informative and close to what I am trying get answered to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C language got standardized by ISO. It is now published as ISO 9899. This standard gets updated from time to time, so there are different version of the standard. Most notably `ISO 9899:1990`, `ISO 9899:1999` and `ISO 9899:2011`, commonly referred to as C89/C90, C99 and C11.

Before it was taken up by ISO, the language mostly was defined by the original authors, which is commonly called K&R C.

**EDIT:** Since the OP clarified it is not about the history or standardization of the language, I can add that the Linux kernel is currently using GNU89 as the language base (Which was made explicit when GCC changed the default to GNU11 in the 5.0 release).

Comment: Note that there is even older C that went through many changes even before K&R first essentially standardized C (before ANSI did). I wasn't sure if OP meant classic C as even before K&R days? But probably not...?

Comment: Downvoted as OP specifically said that he is not asking about the standardization of C.

Comment: @RastaJedi Everything before standardization is generally referred to as "K&R C". There was no standard even after the 1st edition of the K&R book, it was merely the only form of canon people had. If the language was poorly specified before the release of the book, Mr R is to blame for that anyhow.

Comment: @FUZxxl Mea culpa because I wasn't specific enough. I've added some details.

Comment: @Lundin yeah I didn't mean that K&R was the first 'official' standardized C, but that it was referred to as a sort of standard before ANSI C. Sorry for using the term so loosely.